# Is there a certain policy with yes/no questions?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, policy

I always feel weird posting yes or no questions because in short someone ultimately answers the question with a simple 2 or 3 letter word and then I'm choosing a correct answer that didn't really give me any insight other than a confirmation that I did something right... Is there a way that I can just not choose a correct answer and let the question serve as an example for someone else down the road that may be stuck? Also are yes/no questions generally frowned down upon?

Comment: @5pm: That sounds like an answer :-)

Comment: Yes I suppose you're right, I guess looking back, I have just had a few people that answer with a plain yes or no and then that's the only answer I get. But yes you are right, hearing the reasoning is helpful.

Comment: @robjohn OK, moved to another pocket.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/asking-questions-with-very-short-answers

Comment: I just noticed you have 1,337 reputation at the moment, Kyle.

Comment: Is this a yes/no question?

Comment: Simply answering 'Yes' or 'No' wont work. An answer must comprise at least 25 characters.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Related: [Asking questions with very short answers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/asking-questions-with-very-short-answers). The consensus there was that such questions are fine.

That said, don't you also want to know **why** the answer is yes or no? Also, you may be interested in a more general statement than a simple yes/no for a particular example. For instance, along with the yes/no question

> is $10\min(x,y)=\min(10x,10y)$?

you could ask

> More generally, for which numbers $c$ is it true that $c\min(x,y)=\min(cx,cy)$?

Answer (score 7):

No.${}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: Does this answer "Is there a certain policy with yes/no questions?", or "Is there a way that I can just not choose a correct answer and let the question serve as an example for someone else down the road that may be stuck?", or "are yes/no questions generally frowned down upon?" // Or all of the above?

Comment: @5pm: you're going to take all the mystery out of life. :-)

Comment: @5pm yes...$\phantom{no}$

Answer (score 3):

Yes. $\phantom{You can kill me/downvote me to oblivion/suspend me for this comment now.}$

Comment: A more real answer: I'm not too well-versed on general policy here, but by my intuition I'd say you can ask the question if it's possible for people to elaborate on the answer past just a simple yes/no. And people answering the question should elaborate if they can do so.